# Can't start OpenVPN server on Linux

Tags: server, 20.04, vpn, openvpn

I am creating my own OpenVPN server on DigitalOcean using [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-and-configure-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-20-04) guideline.

I have problem starting from step 10. I just can't start start this server and get error all the time.

The guide says, that I need to execute 2 commands - `sudo systemctl -f enable openvpn-server@server.service` and `sudo systemctl start openvpn-server@server.service`.

After execution of the first one it seems like just nothing happens, but after execution of the second one I get this:

```
sammy@OpenVPN-Server:/etc/openvpn/server$ sudo systemctl start openvpn-server@server.service
Job for openvpn-server@server.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status openvpn-server@server.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

And here is interesting thing, this is result, that I have got while trying to get all `openvpn` services. As you can see, there is no such - `openvpn-server@server.service` - service:

```
sammy@OpenVPN-Server:/etc/openvpn/server$ sudo systemctl list-unit-files | grep openvpn
openvpn-client@.service                    disabled        enabled
openvpn-server@.service                    indirect        enabled
openvpn.service                            enabled         enabled
openvpn@.service                           disabled        enabled
```

Also I tried to play with it and start other services, but seems hopeless. What should I do?

Here is some configurations from my `server.conf` file:

```
sammy@OpenVPN-Server:/etc/openvpn/server$ ls
ca.crt  server.conf  server.crt  server.key

...
# Also tried with just names, still doesn't work
ca /etc/openvpn/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/server.key
```

Comment: The guide you're reading is two years old, it's completely possible that `openvpn-server@server.service` is now called `openvpn-server@.service`. Also, there is never a need to to enable and then start, you can always do `systemctl enable [service] --now` to do both at once.

Comment: Do you get errors when starting the openvpn service manually? 
`/usr/sbin/openvpn --status /run/openvpn/server.status 10 --cd /etc/openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/server.conf --writepid /run/openvpn/server.pid`
You will get a nice log. If yes, please fix configuration errors first.

Comment: @dummyuser Thanks you so much, using this command I have found my error!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [dummyuser](https://askubuntu.com/users/1618155/dummyuser) I was able to find the error. Using this command - `/usr/sbin/openvpn --status /run/openvpn/server.status 10 --cd /etc/openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/server/server.conf --writepid /run/openvpn/server.pid` - I was able to list nice log. There, I had error with this `server.conf` line:

```
# EXAMPLE: Suppose the client
# having the certificate common name "Thelonious"
# also has a small subnet behind his connecting
# machine, such as 192.168.40.128/255.255.255.248.
# First, uncomment out these lines:
client-config-dir ccd
```

This option was uncommented, and I had error, that there is no such folder. So, you can either create it or comment this line.